# R data import & transformation

Tags: r, regression

I have a data file with M lines, each of which contains N white-space separated decimal values.  There is no header row.

Each row contains the "Y" portion of N different {X,Y} tuples.  The "X" portion is "position" / 100.  So if a row started out "5, 6, 7" then those would imply to the tuples {0.01, 5}, {0.02, 6}, {0.03, 7}.

For each row I need to compute a least squares fit and extract the slope.  The end result should a vector (a) containing the M slope values.

Here is what I have so far.  It works, but is slow and probably more complicated than necessary:

```
table <- read.table("data.txt", header = FALSE)

x = c()
for (i in 1:length(table)) {
    x <- append(x, 0.01 * i)
}

a = c()
for (i in 1:length(table[,1])) {
    a <- append(a, lm(unlist(table[i,], use.names = FALSE) ~ x)$coefficients[[2]])
}
```

Some specific questions:

1. Is there a better way to generate the (x) vector than appending inside a for-loop?
2. Do I even need the (x) vector, or is there a way to pass the lm() function a single vector of "Y" values and have it infer the "X" values from position?
3. Is there an easy way to import the data into a "vector of vectors" instead of R's "table" structure?

I'm brand new to R, so any improvements you can suggest will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Row-wise operations are much easier if your data is stored as a `matrix`, vs. a `data.frame` (which is what `read.table` returns).

Recreate data:

```
DT <- data.frame(V1 = c(5,7,9), V2 = c(6 , 10 , 8), V3 = c(7,12,4))
```

(Note `table` is the name of a function in R, so you should avoid using it as a variable. I've used `DT` instead)

```
DT <- as.matrix(DT) #convert to matrix
colnames(DT) <- c(1:ncol(DT)) #name your columns 1, 2, 3, ... to the total number of columns.
```

We can now use [apply](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) (example #1 at the link) to apply the same function to each row in our matrix.

```
apply(DT, 1, function(a){
  lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(y = a, x = as.numeric(colnames(DT))/100))$coefficients[[2]]
})
```

Our function takes the row, creates a two column data frame with the row and our `colnames` vector of `1,2,3, ... / 100` created earlier, and finds the least squares fit. If you want to return the entire `lm` model, just take out the `$coefficients[[2]]` (I left in in to replicate your code above.